# Stub a controller helper method in a helper spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec2, rspec-rails

In my `application_controller.rb`:

```
helper_method :current_brand
def current_brand
  @brand ||= Brand.find_by_organization_id(current_user.organization_id)
end
```

In my helper `something_helper.rb`

```
def brands
  return [] unless can? :read, Brand
  # current_brand is called
end
```

I am writing a spec for `something_helper` and wish to stub `current_brand`

```
describe SomethingHelper do
  before :each do
    helper.stub!(:can?).and_return(true) # This stub works
  end

  it "does the extraordinary" do
    brand = Factory.create(:brand)
    helper.stub!(:current_brand).and_return(brand) # This stub doesnt work
    helper.brands.should_not be_empty
  end
end
```

Results in `NameError:
       undefined local variable or method 'current_brand' for #<#<Class:0x000001068fd188>:0x0000010316f6f8>`

I have tried doing the `stub!` on `self` and `controller` as well. Strangely, when I stub on `self`, the `helper.stub!(:can?).and_return(true)` gets unregistered.

Comment: It looks like `#current_brand` isn't a method on your helper, but instead is a method in your controller. Can you move this method into the SomethingHelper?

Comment: Jesse, I _could_ but I would rather not as `current_brand` is used by both the controller and view. When `#current_brand` is defined on the helper directly, the tests pass.

Comment: What does current_brand do? what inputs does it take to make its decision?

Comment: I updated the question to include the implementation. It simply returns the brand belonging to the user. Normally I would make this a method directly on the user (`User#brand`) but the two are in separate engines and stored in different databases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, how about something else... You're really asking Brand.for_user

So:

```
class Brand
  ...
  def self.for_user(user)
    find_by_organization_id(user.organization_id)
  end
end
```

Then, you'd just:

```
brand = mock(Brand)
Brand.stub(:for_user => brand)
```

Or something similar... If you extract that logic out to something that is easily stubbable, it'll make things easier. A Presenter class, perhaps, or this static method.

Comment: Yea, this is probably what I will end up doing. The one thing I like about it being as a controller helper is that it is scoped by the request. So I can have @current_brand and only look it up once. Of course, I can do this with the static method as well, but its not as clean. I am going to leave the question up a bit longer before accepting.

Comment: You could still do this and stub the new method instead of current_brand. `def current_brand
  @brand ||= Brand.for_user(current_user)
end`

Comment: I ended up creating a mixin for the User model so I can just call current_user.brand. Thanks for putting me on the right path though!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something similar to:

`ApplicationController.stub!(:current_brand).and_return(brand)`